# Integrating Apache Shiro with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, shiro

I'm looking at using [Apache Shiro](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHIRO/Index) as a central authentication service for all our applications over a variety of platforms.

It's hinted at that it can [integrate with a variety of platforms](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHIRO/Architecture) which would be ideal for my purposes but I cannot find any examples of how this is achieved from .NET (ASP.NET MVC specifically if it makes any difference).

Does anyone know where I can find an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I know of an effort to port Apache Shiro to .NET in its entirety, but it is probably only 30% complete and not yet publicly accessible.

In the meantime, what most people do is have a web service that is backed by Shiro that can respond to any client as necessary.  Since .NET works quite well with web services, it's not much of a stretch to have the web service APIs reflect Shiro's APIs.

For example, it can be common to expose a 'LoginService' or a 'SubjectService' web service.  There is currently nothing in Shiro's codebase that will provide this out of the box, as it is usually very environment-specific, but hopefully this gives you some ideas.  I've seen people do identical things for supporting Flex applications as well.

HTH!

Les Hazlewood
(Apache Shiro team)

P.S. My company, Katasoft - http://www.katasoft.com -  is building exactly such a product that will work w/ Java, .NET, Ruby, etc.  If you're interested in using it (potentially for free!) please contact us via the form on our home page.

Comment: Thanks Les, I thought that might be the case but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.